# Matching and Updating the current dataframe in PANDAS

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample DataFrame
data = {'A': [1, 2, 3],
       'B': [4, 5, 6],
        'ST_GR': [1, 2, 3],
         'SEC': [1, 2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

GROUP = ['SEC', 'ST_GR']
VALUES = [['Z', 'ZZ'], ['Z', 'ST_GR'], ['SEC', 'Z'], ['SEC', 'ST_GR']]

# Create a dictionary to store the updates
updates = {}

# Iterate through GROUP and VALUES
for group_item, sub_value in zip(GROUP, VALUES):
    if group_item in df.columns:
       for value in range(len(sub_value)):
           updates[group_item] = sub_value[value]
           print(updates)

# Update the DataFrame with the specified values
df.update(pd.DataFrame(updates, index=df.index))

print("Updated DataFrame:")
print(df)
```

I want to make the code memory efficient, So I want that a single dataframe will be generated then the GROUP variables of original dataframe will be updated in every iteration.

I am having this problem, I have a set of GROUP variables and a list with sub-list VALUES. Now, I want this from the code but not getting exact results.

1. In first iteration - df['SEC'] = 'Z' and df['ST_GR'] = 'ZZ' ,
2. In second iteration  - df['SEC'] = 'Z' and df['ST_GR'] value will remain same
3. In third iteration  - df['SEC'] value will remain same and df['ST_GR'] = 'Z'
4. In fourth iteration  - df['SEC'] value will remain same and df['ST_GR'] value will remain same

The Requirement:

1st Iteration:

```
   A  B  ST_GR SEC
0  1  4    Z    ZZ
1  2  5    Z    ZZ
2  3  6    Z    ZZ
```

2nd Iteration:

```
   A  B  ST_GR SEC
0  1  4    1    Z
1  2  5    2    Z
2  3  6    3    Z
```

3rd Iteration:

```
   A  B  ST_GR SEC
0  1  4    Z    1
1  2  5    Z    2
2  3  6    Z    4
```

4th Iteration:

```
   A  B  ST_GR SEC
0  1  4    1    1
1  2  5    2    2
2  3  6    3    4
```

Comment: @Scott Boston  do you have any solution?

Comment: see [@mozway solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77234432/6361531).  I like this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need a single loop and [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
for l in VALUES:                      # for each sublist
    d = {k:v for k,v in zip(GROUP, l) # keep the values ≠ column name
         if k != v}
    print(df.assign(**d))             # assign as new values
```

This only keeps the original DataFrame and updates it at each step

Output:

```
   A  B ST_GR SEC
0  1  4    ZZ   Z
1  2  5    ZZ   Z
2  3  6    ZZ   Z
   A  B  ST_GR SEC
0  1  4      1   Z
1  2  5      2   Z
2  3  6      3   Z
   A  B ST_GR  SEC
0  1  4     Z    1
1  2  5     Z    2
2  3  6     Z    4
   A  B  ST_GR  SEC
0  1  4      1    1
1  2  5      2    2
2  3  6      3    4
```

Comment: I like this solution, although you do have two loops here.  ;-)   The for loop amd the dictionary conprehension.

Comment: @ScottBoston I was almost sure someone would eventually say this :p

Comment: Hehehe... It is fun to be smartbutt sometimes.   You got my +1.